# run java program in another java program

Tags: java, file, exec

hi my program don't work correctly. have sub process java program follow down, when I execute the sub process alone file is created but when I use the `runtime.getruntime().exec(child)` in another program and run then it is not creating file in child program. so why it is not creating ?
I want to create the file when I run the father process i.e text.txt created from child :

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try{

        RandomAccessFile myfile=new RandomAccessFile("XXYYAA.jpg","rw");
        System.out.println("ffff");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {


        //RandomAccessFile a=new RandomAccessFile("C:\\Users\\mohammad\\Documents\\asd.txt","rw");
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Myproject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, it is difficult to understand your question.  can you try to improve it?  see [ask].  can you include more of your code?

Comment: inside the main function I have used RandomAccessFile myfile=new RandomAccessFile("input.txt","rw") .when run my main function create a file near the orginal code.in another main I used runtime.getruntime().exec() and inside argument pass the address of first main to run process of first main .I expect when run second main used exec .run first program have RandomAccessFile myfile too and creat a file near source but not to do. why?

Comment: please move your explanation to the question, that way others are more likely to notice it.